# Unique vector composed of one element from every column of a matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, unique, element

I have an n-by-k matrix in Matlab. I need to take one element from each column to construct a vector of length k with no repeated elements, if such a vector exists. I am not certain how I can go about finding this vector.

Example 1: A matrix X=[1,1,1;2,2,1;3,1,1] has a vector with unique elements v=[3,2,1] in which 3 is selected from the first column, 2 is selected from the second, and 1 from the third.

Example 2: A matrix Y=[1,1,2;1,1,3] does not have such a vector since if I were to select an element from the first column and an element from the second column, I would have two 1's for certain. Therefore, I would not have unique elements in my vector.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a recursive function that iterates over the next vector and checks whether a new element is available, if yes, go to the next vector (as part of the original matrix), if no return.

As a starting point for writing recursive Matlab functions, check: [Recursive Function in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13311289/recursive-function-in-matlab)